# css dropdown hover on just one text (not navbar) but the area of list-style

Tags: html, css

I want to make css dropdown hover on just one text  (not navbar) 
but it show the area of list-style. Even though, you write list-style:none but it still have area  you can see white background color side by list.  How can I delete that list-style area?

HTML

```css
body {
  background: grey;
}
.toptext {
  margin-top: 1vh;
  margin-bottom: 1vh;
}
.toptext span a {
  padding: 3px;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: lightblue;
}
.toptext span a:hover {
  background: #0052cc;
}
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  margin-top: 0px;
}
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="toptext">
  <span style='float:left;'> Welcome! Username </span>
  <span class='dropdown' style='float:left;'>
    <a href='#'>Account</a>
    <ol class='dropdown-content'>
      <li><a href='#'>Edit Profile</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>Log out </a></li>
    </ol>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: what is question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove default `margin` and `padding` of `ol`

```css
body {
  background: grey;
}
.toptext {
  margin-top: 1vh;
  margin-bottom: 1vh;
}
.toptext span a {
  padding: 3px;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: lightblue;
}
.toptext span a:hover {
  background: #0052cc;
}
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  list-style:none;
}
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="toptext">
  <span style='float:left;'> Welcome! Username </span>
  <span class='dropdown' style='float:left;'>
    <a href='#'>Account</a>
    <ol class='dropdown-content'>
      <li><a href='#'>Edit Profile</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>Log out </a></li>
    </ol>
  </span>
</div>
```